# Why can not I get my class methods defined as an array of instances of the index contains the variable?

Tags: xcode, swift

That's what we have. It's Swift code:

```
class Process {
// Some methods and properties
}

class SomeClass {
    var list: [Process]? = nil
// ...
    func someFunc () {
    // ...
    if list !=nil {
            for i in list! {
                if list[i].
    }
}
```

Inserting a point (`.`) in the last line, I do not get a list of methods and properties. 

If I change the index `i` to digit, then I'll get a list of methods and properties of its class Process
[How it's look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCzSr.png)
What should I do to use a variable in the index I could use the methods of its class? 
P.S. Sorry for my English, I used machine translation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `for x in y` you don't have to subscript because `x` is not an index, it's the current iterator object:

```
func someFunc () {
    if let list = list {
        for item in list {
            item.
        }       ^^^^ here auto-suggest will work
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer!

Answer (score 0):

If the suggested methods don't work or don't make sense it's usually because you have a syntax error. Same for auto-indenting the code.

Here what you're doing is iterating the `list`, and expecting that to give you an index, when what it's really doing is giving you the objects in `list`.

So the code should simply be:

```
for i in list! {
    if i.XXX ...
```

where `XXX` is whatever you're trying to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer!

Comment: No problem, and welcome to SO. Please vote and tick answers that help and solve ;-)